Question from an Old STEP paper
I found a question from a STEP paper from 1987, which is a preparatory high-level US equivalent exam (J87/P2/1). I have no idea to approach it.

The diagram shows a light inextensible string with particles of masses m, 2m and 3m attached at the points A, B and C, respectively, and with particles of masses pm and qm attached to the ends of the string. The string passes over two smooth pegs H and K and hangs in equilibrium with HA horizontal and with AB inclined at an angle of 30° to the horizontal. Show that p = √3 and find the tension in AB. Show that the angle of inclination of BC to the horizontal is 60° and find the tension in BC. Find the value of q and the tangent of the angle of inclination of CK to the horizontal. (J87/P2/1)

I made several attempts but am clueless of how to attempt this question, though it seems interesting to me, here is the diagram,:


Start from the equilibrium conditions on the mass $m$ at point A and make deductions. Then repeat with B and so forth.

@semiclassical thanks! Could you please post an answer explaining in detail how to make these equations and finding angle of inclination at these points? Not full answer but I want to know how to do that exactly,

You would get more help if you showed what you have tried yourself. @Semiclassical has indicated what you need to do btw
